# Checking if YouTube Video exists in playlist with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api

I currently have the code below to look for new YouTube video links (video IDs) in my spreadsheet. Is there any way I can search through the YouTube playlist that already exists and check its contents before adding a new video to that? I've seen various examples in PHP but none in Google Apps Script.

```
function addVideoToYouTubePlaylist() {
  // Read the source videos from Google Sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var playlistId = "PL6bCFcS8yqQxSPjwZ9IXFMfVm6kaNGLfi";

  // iterate through all rows in the sheet
  for (var d=1,l=data.length; d<l; d++) {
    
    // Add the video to the existing playlist
    YouTube.PlaylistItems.insert({
      snippet: {
        playlistId: playlistId,
        resourceId: {
          kind: "youtube#video",
          videoId: extractVideoID(data[d][0])
        }
      }
    }, "snippet");

    sheet.deleteRow(d+1); 

    // wait for a second to avoid hitting the rate limit
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
  }
}

function extractVideoID(url){
    var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    if ( match && match[7].length == 11 ){
        return match[7];
    } else {
        console.log("Could not extract video ID.");
        var trimmedVideoID = url.replace("https://youtu.be/", "");
        trimmedVideoID = trimmedVideoID.replace('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', "");
        trimmedVideoID = trimmedVideoID.replace('https://youtube.com/watch?v=', "");
        trimmedVideoID = trimmedVideoID.replace("&feature=youtu.be", "");
        trimmedVideoID = trimmedVideoID.replace("&feature=share", "");
        console.log(trimmedVideoID);
        return trimmedVideoID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to add the video IDs by checking the playlist.
- You want to retrieve the additional video IDs from the column "A" of the active sheet on Google Spreadsheet.
- When the video IDs are existing in the playlist, you don't want to add them.
- When the video IDs are not existing in the playlist, you want to add them.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, I think that at first, it is required to retrieve the list from the playlist. And then, when the additional video ID is not existing in the playlist, the video ID is added.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function addVideoToYouTubePlaylist() {
  // 1. Retrieve list from the playlist.
  var playlistId = "PL6bCFcS8yqQxSPjwZ9IXFMfVm6kaNGLfi";
  var list = [];
  var pageToken = "";
  do {
    var res = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list(["snippet"], {playlistId: playlistId, maxResults: 50, pageToken: pageToken});
    if (res.items.length > 0) list = list.concat(res.items);
    pageToken = res.nextPageToken || "";
  } while (pageToken);
  var obj = list.reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, {[e.snippet.resourceId.videoId]: e.snippet.resourceId.videoId}), {});

  // 2. Retrieve URLs like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=###` from the column "A" of the active sheet.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // 3. Check whether the additional video ID is existing in the playlist and add it.
  data.forEach(([a]) => {
    var videoId = extractVideoID(a);
    if (videoId && !obj[videoId]) {  // <--- Modified
      YouTube.PlaylistItems.insert({
        snippet: {
          playlistId: playlistId,
          resourceId: {
            kind: "youtube#video",
            videoId: videoId
          }
        }
      }, "snippet");
    }
  });
}

function extractVideoID(url){
    var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    if (!match) return;  // <--- Added
    if ( match && match[7].length == 11 ){
        return match[7];
    } else {
        console.log("Could not extract video ID.");
        var trimmedVideoID = url.replace("https://youtu.be/", "");
        trimmedVideoID = trimmedVideoID.replace('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', "");
        trimmedVideoID = trimmedVideoID.replace('https://youtube.com/watch?v=', "");
        trimmedVideoID = trimmedVideoID.replace("&feature=youtu.be", "");
        trimmedVideoID = trimmedVideoID.replace("&feature=share", "");
        console.log(trimmedVideoID);
        return trimmedVideoID;
    }
}
```

#### Note:

- If you have a lot of additional video IDs, to use the batch request might be useful. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#march-11,-2015)

#### References:

- [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list)
- [PlaylistItems: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert)

Comment: Great solution! Thank you for explaining everything in detail as well.

Comment: @Frank Doe Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Unfortuantely I don't think I tested it further enough. I am getting a `Video not found.
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:15
addVideoToYouTubePlaylist @ Code.gs:12` error. And I tried simply implementing the code with my current code and it still allowed the duplicates in the playlist.

Comment: It seems that it only pulls 7 video IDs from the playlist.

Comment: @Frank Doe Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I think your error message of `Video not found` indicates that the video of video ID is not found. So I thought that in your Spreadsheet, no YouTube URLs might be included. From your question, I couldn't supposed this. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. For this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize again. At that time, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: That error in specific was related to the fact that I had a header row in my spreadsheet. When I tried to route it down further, I think it's due to the fact that the obj variable only holds 7 video ID's in it.

Comment: @Frank Doe Thank you for replying. In above updated script, when the header row is included, `match` in `extractVideoID` becomes undefined and the value is not used as the video ID. Can you confirm it? By the way, I cannot understand about `the obj variable only holds 7 video ID's in it`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227775/discussion-between-frank-doe-and-tanaike).